# Finding number of roots of the polynomial $\,\,x^3-x\,$ in $\,\,\Bbb Z /6 \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> The number of roots of the polynomial $x^3-x$ in $\Bbb Z /6 \Bbb Z$ is : $1,2,3,6.$

I have to pick the correct choice.

Since  $\,\,\Bbb Z /6 \Bbb Z=\{\overline 0,\overline 1,\overline 2,.....,\overline 5\}$ and we see $\overline 0,\overline 1$ satisfies $x^3-x=0$ and so the number of roots the polynomial $x^3-x$ in $\Bbb Z /6 \Bbb Z$ is $2$. Am I right?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: $2\cdot 3 \mid (x-1)x(x+1)$.

Comment: *$0,1$ satisfies $x^3-x=0$ and so the number of roots [...] is 2.* Why did you stop your reasoning there?! Even if you made the mistake of assuming it would only have at most as many roots as its degree, you stopped at $2$.. very puzzling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\overline{2}^3 = \overline{8} = \overline{2}$$$$\overline{3}^3 = \overline{27} = \overline{3}$$$$\overline{4}^3 = \overline{64} = \overline{4}$$$$\overline{5}^3 = \overline{125} = \overline{5}$$

So the correct answer is 6.